# Open Microsoft Edge in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, websites, xdg-open

I run Ubuntu on my Windows laptop, and I only use the Microsoft Edge browser. I tried to used the 'xdg-open' to open the desire website, but Microsoft Edge is not listed in the supported browser.

[image]

Can I use something like microsoft-edge https://youtube.com?

Answer (score 0):

The Edge browser from windows is not the one you use in Ubuntu. [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?ep=313&form=MA13M0&es=40) the DEB, install it through software center and it will be available as a suggested browser.

Comment: If that not the case, can I maybe use a reference to the Microsoft Edge with the argument of the website that I want to visit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you install the `.deb` package from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge, you can use the following command the start **MS Edge** directly and load the page you want:

```
$ /opt/microsoft/msedge/msedge https://google.com
```